STM32F030 - What is Heap start and end address with IAR
My uC (STM32F30K6T6) is full in RAM memory.
To optimize the RAM size, I have planned to reduce the Heap Size Memory (initial Heap size is 0x400).
I do not use any manual memory allocation so, I think I will set it to a quarter of it (0x100), just in case.
How to check and know the exact start and end addresses of the heap memory ? This, to check, in debug mode, the live usage (using IAR RAM memory live watch) of each.
The .map file just give that piece of information:
define block CSTACK with size = 1K, alignment = 8 { };
define block HEAP with size = 1K, alignment = 8 { };
"P2":  place in [from 0x2000'0000 to 0x2000'0fff] {
          rw, block CSTACK, block HEAP };

Also, I have reduced the heap size as mentionned above, but I have the same issue while compiling (with IAR). Any explanation?
Linking 
Error[Lp011]: section placement failed 
            unable to allocate space for sections/blocks with a total estimated minimum size of 0x1004 bytes (max align 0x8) in <[0x2000'0000-0x2000'0fff]> (total uncommitted space 0x1000). 
Error[Lp021]: the destination for compressed initializer batch "P2-1" is placed at an address that is dependent on the size of the batch, which is not allowed when using packbits compression. Consider using "initialize by copy with packing  
= zeros" (or none) instead. 
Error while running Linker 


If you do not use heap at all, why don't you remove it completely? Set heap size to 0, or remove block HEAP from place in statement in your linker config file. You shouldn't be using heap anyway in low end embedded systems.

Yes, sure, it was just in case if one day I need to use it. Anyway, unfortunately, I have just learned that if toolchain doesn't see any dynamic allocation function into the code, despite the heap size is specified, it doesn't allocate memory at all for heap

That makes sense. It seems that you simply have too much stuff going into that memory section. You could temporarily reduce the stack size to allow linker to pass successfully. This might give you more information in map file about objects that go in that section, and help to figure out what you need to remove or trim.
